# Angular2 store losing data after navigation

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

I have an Angular2 app written in TS that's using Ionic for state and page routing.

Rough layout is as follows; type.component.html is the view for type.component.ts, which imports a store type.store.ts, which extends a class base.store.ts

I am attempting to inject the store as a singleton into my app, as it's just database CRUD ops on types, doesn't do much interesting, and the same datasets will be presented in multiple components.

Plunkr which demonstrates defect (just view store, go back using upper left back button, view store again... data is missing). http://embed.plnkr.co/M5FO3CKQsvOSacTbkgdV/

The bug is here, if I;

1. Navigate to the page, the base.store and type.store's constructors get called, data gets initialized, and displays on the screen.
2. I can add/edit/delete at leisure, both the database and the component view all update perfectly as I'd expect.
3. I can even go to an other component, identically defined using a different store which extends the same base.store (also identical). Same behavior, it shows up and I can interact with it.
4. However; once I leave for another page, then back to the same, the dataset is empty or not showing on the page; and constructors or load events are not firing.

I am thinking perhaps it's to do with the way my store inheritance is setup, or else I'm not sure.

Relevant code:

component.html

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let type of types$ | async">
  {{type.name}}
</ion-item>
```

component.ts

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/components/types.component.html'
})
export class TypesComponent {    
  private types$: Observable<Array<Type>>;    
  constructor(private navController: NavController, private typeStore: LiftTypeStore) {
    this.types$ = this.typeStore.types$; }}
```

store.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class TypeStore extends BaseStore {

  protected _subject$: Subject<Array<Type>>;
  options;

  constructor(protected http: Http, protected configService: ConfigService) {
    super(http, configService);

    this.options = {
      collection: "types",
      model: "Type",
      route: "types"
    };
    this.init(this.options);
  }

  get types$() {
    return this._subject$.asObservable();
  }
```

base.store.ts

```
export class BaseStore {

  protected options: {
    collection: string,
    model: string,
    route: string
  };
  protected _subject$: Subject<Array<any>>;
  protected dataStore: {};

  constructor(protected http: Http, protected configService: ConfigService) {
  }
  init(options) {
    this.options = options;
    this.dataStore = {};
    this.dataStore[options.collection] = [];
    this._subject$ = <Subject<Array<any>>>new Subject();
    this.load();
  }

  load() {
    this.http.get(this.configService.getBaseUrl() + this.options.route).map(response => response.json()).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log("base store load");
        this.dataStore[this.options.collection] = data;
        this._subject$.next(this.dataStore[this.options.collection]);
      },
      error => console.log('Could not load', this.options.collection));
  }
```

and in app.ts

```
ionicBootstrap(MyApp, [ConfigService, TypeStore, LogStore]);
```

Comment: This seems odd. Could you somehow create a Plunker with these code and mocked data so we can play with?

Comment: @HarryNinh Got it reproducing in a Plunkr, same tech stack and setup across, http://embed.plnkr.co/M5FO3CKQsvOSacTbkgdV/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, fixed it...

Turns out injecting the store App wide during bootstrap was causing the issue. Once I removed from there and added as a provider to [providers] in Component constructor, everything worked perfectly.

I'm not sure why this would happen, since the only difference *should* be the store gets instantiated once, then passed around to anyone who wants it. Now it gets created each time the component is. But, defect resolved...